# How do i fail docker run when my sh script fails inside

Tags: docker, gitlab, sh, gitlab-ci

I have a file which installs some tools which we need. After installation of tools, my sh script is validating the installation and if any tool isn't found then it should fail. I am using this approach in my gitlab-ci file.

The sh script works fine and exit out but when i use it in docker run , docker doesn't exit out with error.

**test.sh:**

```
    echo "Validating Docker Installation"
    which docker
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
       docker --version | grep "Docker Version"
       if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
       then
          echo "Docker installed successfully"
       else
          echo $?
          exit 1
        fi
    else
     echo "Docker didnt installed"
     exit 1
    fi
```

**gitlab-ci.yml(Test job)**

```
test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO:$BUILD_VERSION
    - docker run --rm $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO:$BUILD_VERSION sh ./test.sh
```

Comment: Have you considered running this script, when building the actual image instead of when the container starts?

Comment: Yes and its not failing at all... i am testing script with having no docker installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitLab's jobs will fail any time a job exits with a non-0 status code from the last command. So really, the question you're asking here is "How do I make `docker run` return the status code of the script run within the container?" The answer is that you can't - you have to query the status code of the script once the container is done running, then use "exit" to raise that same status code. If you run `exit 0`, the job will succeed. If you run `exit 1`, it will fail. To put that together with your example, you get the below example, using the `docker inspect` command to pull the exit code of the run container, which I've now named `test` so we can easily pull the exit code in the next command.

Now, if your container returns a non-0 exit code, the next command will essentially echo that exit code, causing your job to pass or fail based on the status of the run container.

```
test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO:$BUILD_VERSION
    - docker run --name test --rm $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_REPO:$BUILD_VERSION sh ./test.sh
    - exit $(docker inspect test --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}')
```

Comment: Perfect !! That is something i was looking for... got the idea now... Thanks a lot.